# Saving data with FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I recently have begun using fullcalendar and was just wondering how to save events that were set on the calendar by using ajax and passing the data to a php file which saves the data into a database. Basically what I am trying to accomplish is that when someone makes an event on the calendar (by clicking the field) after they have done that, insert the data for that event into a database with the date of the event. Can this be done?

Thanks!

This is the code I have in place and I'm not sure where to put the ajax part at:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
    },
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        var title = prompt('Event Title:');

        if (title) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                {
                    title:  title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: allDay  
                }, 
            true);
        }

        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable: true,

    eventSources: [
        {

        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.post('url', parameters, callback_function);`(you can use $.post when clicked on an event) to send eid that is entity id to the php file and using that eid you can use 
You can pass the parameters with the field values

```
$node = node_load($eid) // $eid = $_POST['eid'];
```

and then add parameters value
after all changes

```
node_save($node);
```